# Pulp fiction book about magic stone that gave Hitler and others power

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to find the title/author of a pulp fiction paperback I read some 20+ years ago. The basic plot was that a magic stone/gem possessed its holders -- giving them intense charisma, arrogance, and power. Hitler held it, and people who knew about it would kill to get it. At the end, some Mexican farmer (?) digs it up unknowingly and feels it effects as the pages end.

I think it was called something like "The Charisma Gem" or "The Hitler Stone."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

That sounds like [The Messiah Stone](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEYQFjAD&url=http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1445221.The_Messiah_Stone&ei=kUOEUsHIGYfa4AOP2oDIAw&usg=AFQjCNH0MkW0MjUS4CHvt-Cl-nbIHJtrHA&sig2=Ux8d9a40DSbCqe3VcASpuw) [1986] by [Martin Caidin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Caidin).

Except for the very end, you described it fairly well.

To steal from the Blurb:

> Doug Stavers plays the mercenary game, and every time he plays he wins: in Africa, Central America, Vietnam or in the USA. Now he's on the biggest hunt of his life: to find and seize a certain object that, incredibly, confers the power of absolute belief on its owner. Christ once wore it. So did Mohammed. The last to own it was Adolf Hitler. The next will rule the world. It's code name is "The Messiah Stone"

[image]